# WooCommerce hide product image and gallery in single product page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am adding this code to remove product image and gallery in single product page. This works in Wordpress default theme 2021, but not in newest (22 and 23). In newest themes product image and gallery are still shown in single product page.
I cannot figure out what is making them show. I have no other plugins activated except Woocommerce and my own with only this test code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'wpv_woocommerce_before_single_product');


function wpv_woocommerce_before_single_product() {

    remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary','woocommerce_show_product_images', 20 );
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails','woocommerce_show_product_thumbnails', 20 );

}
```